# dropbox does not works in elementary os 6.1+

Tags: dropbox

Goodmorning everybody,

pretending absolutely nothing i am here to ask you a solution to something that is to me, a real storage problem:

is there a way or a software update that will make dropbox applications works by default as a perfect integration in elementary os 6.1+?

Actually GUI do not allow use it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I installed the one from the AppCenter, got the login prompt, and the Dropbox folder in my /home. Everything I put there shows up in my dropbox account and in the Adroid App. The sync works, but it is true there is no visual indication. GUI does not work indeed, but at this point i kinda like it as is.

Comment: I am going to give this a try and see how it works. https://itsubuntu.com/mount-dropbox-folder-locally-linux/

Comment: Yup, you can mount  the dropbox folder locally, no need for a client. When I have some free time, and if you're interested, I can set up a detailed instuctable, but until then the link in the comment above has all you need.

Comment: thanks @Vlad for your response, unluckily this is not a solution...just because dropbox setup for elementary is not for me, but for someone else that is actually a geek so far to understand a "mount" concept. 
But you were very kind, so many thanks for sharing resources and informations

Comment: "mount" means you get to use the dropbox folder like any other drive on your computer. It will show up in your Files as a new drive (like a plugged in USB drive for example) and you can freely copy to it, paste from it, or directly access any files on it. The operations you do on a "mounted" dropbox folder are synced in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer by myself: at this time there's no way to use dropbox in elementary os 6.x.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox does work on elementary, I use it all the time. What is missing is a status indicator, but honestly I don't even notice that anymore.

My one suggestion is to enable Dropbox Syncing on Startup. From a [blog post](https://blog.senderolinux.com/installing-software-on-elementary-os-6/) I wrote:

> After installing Dropbox from the AppCenter (which pulls from
> Flathub), “launch at startup” is not enabled by default. As a
> consequence, by default the Dropbox folders only sync when the Dropbox
> application is launched.
>
> You can launch Dropbox on startup to make the syncing experience more
> automatic. After installing Dropbox from AppCenter, go to System
> Settings > Applications > Startup, and then add Dropbox to this list.